# Tkinter and UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get the coordinates for each square on the board but the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment` keeps showing up when I click on a square.

```
import tkinter
class  RA:
    def __init__(self):
        self._columns = 8
        self._rows = 8
        self._root = tkinter.Tk()
        self._canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master = self._root,
                                      height = 500, width = 500,
                                      background = 'green')
        self._canvas.pack(fill = tkinter.BOTH, expand = True)
        self._canvas.bind('<Configure>',self.draw_handler)

    def run(self):
        self._root.mainloop()

    def draw(self):
        self._canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,250,250,fill = 'blue',outline = 'white')
        self._canvas.create_rectangle(250,250,499,499,fill = 'red',outline = 'white')
        self._canvas.create_rectangle(499,499,250,250,fill = 'black',outline = 'white')
        #
        for c in range(self._columns):
            for r in range(self._rows):
                x1 = c * (column_width)#the width of the column
                y1 = r * (row_height)
                x2 = x1 + (column_width)
                y2 = y1 + (row_height)


    #3-5

    def clicked(self,event: tkinter.Event):
        x = event * x
        y = event * y
        rect = self._canvas.find_closest(x,y)[0]
        coordinates = self._canvas.gettags(rect)
        print(coordinates[0],coordinates[1])

    def draw(self):
        self._canvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
        column_width = self._canvas.winfo_width()/self._columns
        row_height = self._canvas.winfo_height()/self._rows
        for  x in range(self._columns):
            for y in range(self._rows):
                x1 = x * column_width
                y1 = y * row_height
                x2 = x1 + column_width
                y2 = y1 + row_height
                r = self._canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill = 'blue')#,tag = (x,y))# added for the second time,
                self._canvas.tag_bind(r,'<ButtonPress-1>',self.clicked)

                self._canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2)
        self._canvas.bind('<Configure>',self.draw_handler)



    def draw_handler(self,event):
        self.draw()


r = RA()
r.run()
```

Comment: Well what *are* you expecting `x` to be in `clicked`?

Comment: The first thing you do in `clicked()` is try to calculate the value of `event * x`. What is `x`? Perhaps you meant to say `x = event.x`? Same for `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in these two lines:

```
def clicked(self,event: tkinter.Event):
    x = event * x
```

You're  using `x` on the right hand side of the expression, but `x` hasn't been defined anywhere. Also, you're going to have a problem because `event` is an object. Multiplying the object times some other number isn't likely going to do what you think it is going to do. Did you maybe intend to use `event.x` in the expression instead of `event * x`?

**Getting the coordinates of the clicked item**

Even though you specifically asked about the unbound local variable error, it appears you're attempting to get the coordinates of the item that was clicked on. Tkinter automatically gives the item that was clicked on the tag `"current"`, which you can use to get the coordinates:

```
coordinates = self._canvas.coords("current")
```

From the official tk documentation:

> The tag current is managed automatically by Tk; it applies to the
>   current item, which is the topmost item whose drawn area covers the
>   position of the mouse cursor (different item types interpret this in
>   varying ways; see the individual item type documentation for details).
>   If the mouse is not in the canvas widget or is not over an item, then
>   no item has the current tag.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen with `y` as well. If you want `x` to be stored with the button, you'll need to create a Class for it, and store them as `self.x` and `self.y`. The `clicked()` event would be on the class itself, and then it will have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you used

```
x = event * x
y = event * y
```

when you probably wanted

```
x = event.x
y = event.y
```

The latter accesses the `event` object's `x` and `y` attributes instead of attempting to multiply it by an unbound variable.